# How to create toggle for symbol in dart (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to create a screen testing app that can show what parts of the screen do not respond to touch.
This should be a very simple, single-screen application with a table of symbols that can be clicked to test the screen.

I have the table of symbols working, but cannot find how to make the symbols toggle when clicked.
How can I make each icon have it's own toggle without building almost 100 separate variable (or an array).
Can Icons have properties?

I am getting the following error when trying to use onTap (which I got from the flutter demo app, but can't get to work properly in this context.)

Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:33:32: Error: Expected ']' before this.
onTap: () {
^
lib/main.dart:33:27: Error: The getter 'onTap' isn't defined for the class '_MyAppState'.

'_MyAppState' is from 'package:app1/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onTap'.
onTap: () {
^^^^^

````
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double iconSize = 40;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var toggledOn = false;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Screen Tester'),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Table(
                    border: TableBorder.all(),
                    children: [
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Column(children:[
                          Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,
                              color: toggledOn ? Colors.green : Colors.blue),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (toggledOn = false) {
                                toggledOn = true;
                              } else {
                                toggledOn = false;
                              }
                            });
                          }
                        ]),
                        Column(children:[
                          Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,
                              color: toggledOn ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
                        ]),
                        Column(children:[
                          Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,
                              color: toggledOn ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
                        ]),
                        Column(children:[
                          Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,
                              color: toggledOn ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
                        ]),
                        Column(children:[
                          Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,
                              color: toggledOn ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
                        ])
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,
                            color: toggledOn ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                      TableRow( children: [
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                        Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize,),
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]))),

    );
  }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O019z.png
````

Comment: You want an `IconButton`. Widgets can't spontaneously add properties that they don't have.

Comment: @Christopher Moore I think you are right. please add it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want an `IconButton` to be able to use it's equivalent of `onTap`, `onPressed`. `onTap` parameters can only be passed when they are available to the widget, they can't be used as you wish.

`IconButton` will take your existing `Icon` and allow you to add an `onPressed` callback.
Ex.

```dart
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.adjust, size: iconSize, color: toggledOn ? Colors.green : Colors.blue),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      if (!toggledOn) {
        toggledOn = true;
      } else {
        toggledOn = false;
      }
    });
  },
)
```

Simply tracing the compiler error would be much faster than asking here on SO. They are usually quite easy to fix, especially compared to runtime errors.

Edit:

Additionally, you can't declare `toggledOn` inside of the `build` method. Move it outside of `build` to prevent it from going back to the default value on every `build`. Move it right next to `iconSize`.

Comment: This creates a clickable button but the toggle isn't working (no errors now either).

Comment: @ReactorMatrix Please be specific about "not working".

Comment: @ReactorMatrix There was an issue in the comparison in your original toggling function that I didn't notice, though it should've thrown an error. I made an edit.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it creates the button, I can see that it is responding (I see the ripple effect), but the color (or state) isn't changing

Comment: Ok, that makes the toggle work. Though it is the same toggle for all of the icons, so now comes the real question (from OP).

How can I make each icon have it's own toggle without building almost 100 separate variables (or an array).

An array is the best way I think of to do this, with one entry for each IconButton.
Is there a way to set a property for each IconButton individually, or is the array a good way to do this?

Comment: @ReactorMatrix This is a separate question so you should accept an answer here if it helped and create a new one. However, an array is likely the best way for you to do it, but it really depends on what you plan to do with it.